# Linux signal is not delivered

Tags: linux, signals

I have some PHP daemons that lose some signals. So for example they should receive an ALRM signal to save their statistics once a minute and they stop on TERM signal which sometimes they don't receive. I've always attributed this as PHP weirdness and I have workarounds for example the stopper process resends the TERM signal if my daemon doesn't want to stop. But now I have this perl Net::Server::HTTP (with PreFork) daemon and every once in a while one of it's workers gets stuck, /proc/X/wchan always shows "sk_wait_data" and if I send them an ALRM signal manually they react, it's like the ALRM signal for the socket read timeout was lost. You should also know that all my other similar Net::Server servers never get stuck and I don't know what the difference is. And also that both this and the PHP signal loss happens very rarely, like once every several weeks.

Comment: Please add the code which emits the signal, and the handler.

Comment: Threads can often mess up your signals. In Linux a signal can be delivered to a thread or to a process. If to a process it might be handled by any thread. PHP generally avoids threads but I don't know your configuration.

Comment: Another thing about signals you may need to know is that unless they are the queued real-time signals, they can merge. That means if two SIGALRM signals happen within the same time period (decided by the kernel) only one will be delivered to the process.

Comment: @ZanLynx I don't use threads and looking into /proc PHP did not start any for itself but that doesn't mean it never does, how would I go about verifying that? Should it say something in phpinfo()?